# GCSにアップロードしたファイルのURLが更新されない件

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlet

お世話になっております。

以下環境
Java: 1.7
Eclipse: 4.3
GAE: 1.9.30
Servlet: 2.5
appengine-gcs-client: 0.5

現在GCSに画像ファイルをアップロードし、ファイルのURLを返すとの処理をServletで
行っています。GCSとの連携はGCS Client Libraryを使用しています。

GCSにファイルをアップロードし、再度同じファイル名で別の画像をアップロードすると
URLにアクセスした場合、最初にアップロードされたファイルが表示されます。
GCS内で確認するとファイルは更新されているのですが、URLだけがキャッシュされているようです。

URLの生成方法は
ImagesService#getServingUrl
と
aclをpublic-readにし、公開URLを取得する
この2パターンを試しましたが、どちらもキャッシュされるようです。

このキャッシュの動作を無効化し、常に新しいファイルのURLを返して欲しいのですが、
こうすればできたよって方いらっしゃいませんでしょうか？
ImagesServiceを使いリサイズするといいともあったのですが、リサイズ処理なしでいきたいと
思っております。

cacheControl(“max-age=15”)などし、キャッシュコントロールも触ってみたのですが、
効果ありませんでした。

よろしくお願いいたします。

※追記
無事URLが取得できました。URL差し替えの際にキャッシュされていたようです。

Answer (score 1):

Image Serviceは裏側はG+Photoのインフラを使っていて、Blobstore or Cloud Storageのファイルを、G+Photoにキャッシュしちゃってます。
こちらは、キャッシュ期間を制御する機能は無いんじゃないかなと思います。

キャッシュをまったく利用したくないのであれば、App Engineでは、BlobstoreServiceを使って、Cloud Storageのファイルを配信するのが良いかなと思います。
BlobstoreServiceについては、[GAE/jでファイルを扱う Part2](http://qiita.com/sinmetal/items/7d2617001494cd204255) を見ていただくと良いかなと思います。
後、すでにGCSに存在するファイルをBlobstoreServiceで扱う場合は [Java_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage) を参考にBlobKeyを生成してください。
実際、コード書いてみるとこんな感じですね。
HTTP Response Headerを編集したい場合は、BlobstoreService.serve(blobKey, response);をする前に編集しておけばOKです。

```
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
        BlobKey blobKey =
                blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey("/gs/" + fileName.getBucketName() + "/"
                        + fileName.getObjectName());
        blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, response);
```

Comment: 早速のコメントありがとうございます。毎度お世話になっております。
Google + Photoのインフラを使っているのですね。初耳でした。
ですが、ImageUrlを使わず、ACLにpublic-readを設定した場合はURLの生成にImagesServiceを使用していないのですが、この場合はGCS自体がキャッシュをしているのでしょうかね。。。

part1を含め記事を拝見させて頂きました。
さっそくですが、BlobstoreServiceを使ってCloud Storageのファイルを配信とありますが、これはどのような意味でしょうか？
Part2のFIleDownloadのようにURLを生成せずにBlobstoreService#serveで画像ごと配信をするのがいいとの意味でしょうか？

Comment: Cloud StorageのACLにpublic-read付けると、自動でEdge Cacheに乗せられるようになってるんですよね。
Edge Cacheについては、 http://qiita.com/sinmetal/items/37c105a098174fb6bf77 を見てください。

BlobstoreServiceでCloud Storageファイルの配信というのは、Cloud StorageのObjectのPathからBlobKeyを生成してあげて、BlobstoreService.Serve()するということです。
回答にサンプルコードを追加しておきました。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。Edge Cacheの参考サイトとても参考になります。サンプルコードありがとうございます。sinmetalさんのpart1で紹介されているKeyの生成方法ですね。とても参考にさせて頂いております。